# Using Datetime to convert a pandas dataframe column (string)

Tags: pandas, date

I am trying to convert the following string in datetime format

"14DEC2014"

Does anyone have an advice on how to do this, I have been stuck on this one for a day or two now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing date/time strings in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978022/parsing-date-time-strings-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

test = '14DEC2014'
test = pd.to_datetime(test)
print(test)
```

output:

```
2014-12-14 00:00:00
```

If you would like to only have the date:

```
test = pd.to_datetime(test).date()
```

output:

```
2014-12-14
```